# How can I share a Matplotlib window with Live Share participants in VS Code?

Tags: matplotlib, visual-studio-code, vscode-liveshare

I have to use Live Share with VS Code and a python script that shows some plots. If I execute the program I see the plots, while the person I am sharing with can't.
So my question is if it is possible that the person connected remotely is able to see this matplotlib windows.

I would like to see the matplotlib windows if I am connected remotely through Live Share on VS Code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it opens in a separate window, that's not possible. That's outside the "jurisdiction" of that Live Share session in VS Code. You'll need to use some other screen calling software or have your partner run the shared code on their own machine.

For some in-VS-Code debuggers, I'm pretty sure the Live Share participants can also see the debugger info, and if the program has output to the standard output file stream, they can also see that, but again, anything that appears outside the VS Code window, they cannot see.