# Flutter Dart project (live shared) both a own simulator to test / run the app?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, ios-simulator

Me and my friend are working on a Flutter and Dart app. I created the project and am mostly live sharing it. Can he open a simulator to test the app on iPhone? I see the button to launch it in my simulator, but he doesn't.

He off also installed dart and flutter but still don't see now to fix it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I share a Matplotlib window with Live Share participants in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74631718/how-can-i-share-a-matplotlib-window-with-live-share-participants-in-vs-code)